# Using GET Or POST to retrieve ninja form value

Tags: php, ninja-forms

Is there a way to retrieve ninja form value by redirecting to external URL, using `GET` or `POST` method? I've tried setting field name in ninja form to `"name"`, but the external PHP code can't get it using either `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

I've set the text input name to `"name"`:
[image: I've set the text input name to "name"]

Then redirect it to my custom PHP page:
`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/test.php`

Here's my custom PHP code to retrieve the value:

```php
<?php

$test = $_POST['amount'];
echo 'Amount: ' . $test . '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: can you show the code to help?

Comment: Hi @SolaimanKmail, thanks for answering! I've edited the post and added images with codes to help.

Comment: Please add code as text rather than images.

Comment: are you submitting to external url using the form action attribute? or you did the redirection in another way?

Comment: I redirect it using Form Action under ninja form Emails & Actions

Comment: If _" external PHP code can't get it using either $_POST or $_GET"_ then it must be that form is not getting submitted. Need more info. to decide that

Comment: Because the form I created is using Ninja Form, so it does not allow custom coding to edit it.